# Example of two series with certain properties?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Find 2 series $\sum a_k$ and $\sum b_k$ such that $\sum b_k$ converges conditionally, $\dfrac{a_k}{b_k} \rightarrow 1$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$, and $\sum a_k$ diverges. Can someone give me a hint with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let$$b_n=\dfrac{(-1)^n \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{n}}, \;\; a_n=(-1)^n u_n,\;\;\; n\geqslant {2},$$
where 
$$u_n=\begin{cases}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}-1},&n=2k, \\
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}+1},&n=2k+1, \;\;k\in\mathbb{N}. \end{cases}$$
Partial sums for $\sum{a_n}$ 
$$S_{2k+1}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2k+1}{\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{i+1}-1}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{i+1}+1} \right)}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2k+1}\dfrac{2}{i}\;\underset{k\to\infty}{\;\longrightarrow{\infty}}.$$